# wp widget add custom_html removes tag

Tags: centos, command-line, wordpress

I want to execute wp-cli command but it removes `<script>` tag

```
sudo runuser -l  userName -c 'wp widget add custom_html footer-1 1 --title="" --content="<script>alert(123);</script>" --path="/var/www/userName/data/www/mysite.abc"'
```

CentOS 7

After executing in created widget I get only `alert(123);`
I tried to put it in single quotes, add backslashes and even urlencode() but not successful.